# CoronaSDK: Passing function to a class

Tags: class, events, lua, listener, coronasdk

Maybe is already answered but I cannot find it and probably is because I cannot make the right question.... I will try to explain me:

I made a class that helps me to create buttons and when I click the button is executing a function that is inside the class. I do not know if it's possible but I would like to have the tap / touch function outside the class.

Here the code:

### button.lua

```
function Button.new(posX, posY, size, title)    -- constructor
  local button = tools.loadText( title, posX, posY, "Roboto-Regular", size, {0/255, 0/255, 0/255})
  group:insert( button )
  button.alpha = 0

  local buttonEffect = ButtonEffect.new(posX, posY, 600, button.contentHeight*2)
  group:insert(buttonEffect)

  button:toFront( )

  button.x = posX
  button.y = posY
  button.size = size
  button.title = title
```

---

```
function button:show(delay)
  print( button.title.." --> show" )
  button:addEventListener( "tap", button )

  transition.to(button, { time = 900, alpha = 1, delay = delay, transition=easing.inQuart })
end

function button:tap(event)
  print( self.title.." --> click" )
  self:removeEventListener( "tap", self )

  buttonEffect:click()

  return true
end
```

Here my main.lua

```
local button = require ("classes.Button")
button1 = button.new(540, 1300, 38, "LOGIN")
```

As everytime I create a button will have the same animation but different behavior, I would like to be notified here when user make the tap to have the code outside the class and be able to reuse this class in other projects.

I hope I explained myself.

Comment: Ok, I think I fixed by myself but probably is not the best solution. I removed the tap event inside the class and I created outside. Now I can handle it from the new tap event but I need to call there my animation functions. Maybe has any suggestion about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right you want to specify callback function from outside.

Here are 2 methods:

Passing method from outside when creating

```
function Button.new(posX, posY, size, title, callback)
    ...
    ...
    function button:tap(event) 
        print( self.title.." --> click" ) self:removeEventListener( "tap", self )
        buttonEffect:click()
        callback();
        return true
    end
end

button1 = button.new(540, 1300, 38, "LOGIN", function()
    print("Button clicked");
end);
```

Specifying method after you created

```
function Button.new(posX, posY, size, title, callback)
    ...
    ...
    function button:tap(event) 
        print( self.title.." --> click" ) self:removeEventListener( "tap", self )
        buttonEffect:click()
        if (self.callback) then -- Just to be safe
            self.callback();
        end
        return true
    end
end

button1 = button.new(540, 1300, 38, "LOGIN");
button1.callback = function()
    print("Button clicked");
end
```

Comment: I cannot vote you positive because I do not have enough reputation but that was exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks a lot, master!